# difference between an object property and type property

Tags: python, properties, types

Some one to help me this, What is the difference between an object property and type property? if possible with an example in python.. thanks!

Comment: You might want to say "instance property" and "class property" instead. Everything in Python is an object, and every object has a type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class A:
   class_property = 10

   def __init__(self):
      self.object_property = 20
```

The difference is that you can access class_property through class A:

```
print A.class_property
```

but you can access object_property only through an instance of A:

```
a = A()
print a.object_property
```

Comment: so a class property is the same as a type property?

Comment: Beware that this is an old-style class. To use new-style classes, inherit from object: `class a(object): ...`